# Random Effects Model Set-Up for Repeated Measures?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I have a data set with two measured variables (liking and closeness). I asked participants about these two variables across three different domains (friends, coworkers, siblings). If I want to determine if closeness "predicts" (I know I'm stuck with correlational data here) liking, how would I test this in R?

I know how to do a basic `lme` function, but I'm not quite sure how to add in the random effects of participant.

I've named my variables `PID`, `liking`, `closeness`, and `relation`. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site, srs6012! I would suggest using the `lme4` package for this. You can indeed look at the association between liking and closeness using a random effects/mixed/multilevel model as follows. Make sure that you have coded `relation` as a factor variable with 3 levels:

```
require(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(liking ~ closeness + relation + (1|PID), data=df)
```

This model examines the association adjusting for the type of relationship and accounting for the correlation among liking ratings by the same person (the random effect - `(1|PID)`).

You may want to further test whether the association between closeness and liking is different depending on the relationship. This would require an interaction between `closeness` and `relation`:

```
m2 <- lmer(liking ~ closeness + relation + closeness:relation + (1|PID), data=df)
```

This will tell you the difference in the closeness-liking association for each of the relation groups. You can use the `ggeffects` package to graph these associations:

```
require(ggeffects)
ggpredict(m2, c("closeness", "relation"))%>%plot()
```